# Dismiss keyboard when default ios mail app opens

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my app I display the MFMailComposeViewController to display default mail app. How to dismiss the keyboard which opens up in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIWindow* keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView* firstResponder = [keyWindow performSelector:@selector(firstResponder)];
[firstResponder resignFirstResponder];
```

I hope This Will Help You.. :)

Answer (score 1):

<del>Unfortunately it look's like even if we try to force close the keyboard using `endEditing;` that function takes no effect. On my device it doesn't seem like the keyboard can be dismissed.</del>

<del>Below would have been the answer that should have worked:
Display the `MFMailComposeViewController`with a completion and call `endEditing:` on the `MFMailComposeViewController`'s view.</del>

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:mailVC animated:YES completion:^{ 
     [mailVC.view endEditing:YES];
}];
```

**UPDATE:**

Wouldn't suggest doing this but, here is a hackish way that works:

Objective-C:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:mailVC animated:YES completion:^{
      UITextField *a = [[UITextField alloc] init];
      [mailVC.view addSubview:a];
      [a becomeFirstResponder];
      [mailVC.view endEditing:YES];
}];
```

Swift:

```
let mailVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
self.presentViewController(mailVC, animated: true) { () -> Void in
       let a = UITextField()
       mailVC.view.addSubview(a)
       a.becomeFirstResponder()
       mailVC.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: the solution worked in MFMessageComposeController too.. Thanks.. can I you please how to prevent the keyboard from appearing again when the user taps on the edit text field of MFMessage/MFMail?

Answer (score 1):

In your `viewcontroller.h` add:

```
@property (nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
```

Now in the .m file, add this to your ViewDidLoad function:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad 
{
        [super viewDidLoad];

        //Keyboard stuff
        tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
        tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    }*
```

Also, add this function in the .m file:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```